# Access 2016 - Display foreign key value instead of id

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaVsw.jpg) of my lookup wizard (sorry, I couldn't change the language from german).
But I don't want to display an ID in "Ort". I want to dispay two values the table has instead.

To generalize this question: "How can I show the values of a foreign key in a lookup instead of the id?"

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean foreign key? It's a field in your lookup wizard? You can show whatever you want in lookup column using properties of Columns Widths, Columns Count and Bound Column

Comment: When I click on the field (to which i add this lookup table) to choose a value it looks like this: "KSK | Einzelhandel | 1"

Comment: Exactly. It looks like that because you set it up like that using Wizard. So what do you want now? How do you want it to look like?

Comment: Instead of "1" I want it to say "[ValueOfColumnRegion] | [ValueOfColumnStadt]". So remove the "1" and replace it with values the tables holds in the row of the "1".

Comment: Remake your LookUp Column. Instead of using field [Ort], use those fields you want "[ValueOfColumnRegion] | [ValueOfColumnStadt]"

Answer (score 1):

I expect you want to retrieve and save the Ort value as foreign key, otherwise don't bother to include in query. Set up combobox properties like:

RowSource: SELECT Ort, GName, Typ FROM yourtablename;
BoundColumn: 1
ColumnCount: 3
ColumnWidths: 0";1";2"
ControlSource: the field to save Ort in

I NEVER build lookups in table, only comboboxes or listboxes on form.

Comment: Indeed table lookups lead to very bad habits like direct edits on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but hopefully, I can help someone else, who has the same problem. The best solution, in my opinion, is to join two tables in the RowSource property, and select values from there.
Let's assume that you have the Ort and Typ attribute in the same table as GName. Let's call this table: tableofgname. Let's assume you try to read the value of Ort attribute from a table name tableofort.
In this case you should enter something like this in RowSource: SELECT [tableofgname].[GName], [tableofgname].[Typ], [tableofort].[Ort] FROM tableofgname INNER JOIN tableofort ON [tableofgname].[Ort] = [tableofort].[OrtID]
That way you'll see the value of Ort instead of its ID number.